# wxPython's wx.ListCtrl in simple list mode (not style = wx.LC_REPORT)

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a tutorial on how to use a wx.ListCtrl in (style = wx.LC_REPORT) mode but I only use one column:

```
self.InsertColumn(0, "Item")
```

How can I either:

- stretch the column to take the whole avail. length
- switch to a more basic mode using just one column to begin with?

I don't really need the field label I am using above (i.e. "Item").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [wx.ListBox](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListBox-class.html) control instead of a [wx.ListCtrl](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html).

The display mode of `ListCtrl` closest to what you're looking for is `wx.LC_LIST`, and in that mode the control will render multiple items side-by-side if it has enough horizontal extent.

On the other hand, a simple `ListBox` does exactly what you're looking for.